# Play Framework 2 Ebean Select Records where Join Not Null/Empty

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

I have a very simple DB consisting (for this example) of two tables: `Users` and `UserOrders`

I want to select a list of users where there are `UserOrder` association (so user orders are not NULL).

I have tried using `.isNotNull()`, but either I'm using it wrong, or it doesn't work the way I expect it to.

For example, where `userOrdersList` is the name of the `@ManyToOne` field in the Model:

```
List<User> User.find.where().isNotNull("userOrdersList").findList();
```

and where `UserOrders` is the actual name of the table

```
List<User> User.find.where().isNotNull("UserOrders").findList();
```

I'm kind of new getting back to SQL, but as I recall basically what I'm looking for is a Left Excluding Join (meaning it excludes any null results)